# What's in a name?

Tags: ros, ardent

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,
Hope this doesn't come across as a really stupid question, or should I say, hope this doesn't come across as a question that shows my stupidity......

You have me interested in the name "answers.ros". Can you shed some light on where the name came from and whether it means anything in particular?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317373/what%27s-in-a-name?/) by [nhungthientai](https://answers.ros.org/users/40311/nhungthientai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-03-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-04**:\

> You have me interested in the name "answers.ros". Can you shed some light on where the name came from and whether it means anything in particular?

I'm not sure I completely understand the question: are you asking where the `answers.ros.org` domain name came from?

Or "ROS Answers" itself?

**Comment by [nhungthientai](https://answers.ros.org/users/40311/nhungthientai/) on 2019-03-04**:
"ROS Answers"! Oh, i see. Thank you ^_^

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-09-04**:
Looks like @nhungthientai is a spam account now.

I've changed account status to `watched` and reverted the spam edit to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm by no means an authoritative source for this, but "ROS Answers" (ie: this site) is an instance of something called [Askbot](http://askbot.com/), which is a platform for "Q&A sites". "Q&A" is short for: *Question & Answer*, which is the type of interaction we have here on ROS Answers.

So the name would suggest that this is the place to get answers to questions about ROS (ie: "the Answers site for ROS").

I guess it could have been named "ROS Questions", but that might not be a good name from an English language perspective, as it would imply that there are mostly *questions* here (which may be seen as something negative) while a site that provides *answers* would seem to be more valuable.

As to the domain name: I believe that follows logically from the "ROS Answers" name: `answers.ros.org`.

---

Note btw: `questions.ros.org` does exist. It directly forwards to `answers.ros.org` though.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3